# Dynamically create instance of current collection 

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Firstly, apologies for the title - if anyone has a better version after reading the question, please edit or ask me to.

I have extended the core Backbone Collection object with a 'where' method that allows me to perform an _.select on the models within the collection. Currently this returns a new vanilla Collection object containing the models. What I want is for the method to return a Collection object of the same type as I am calling ...

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.where = function(a) {
  var execute = function(item) {
    ...
  };

  return new Backbone.Collection(this.select(execute));
};

var Accounts = Backbone.Collection.extend({...})
```

What I want, at the return statement is to be returning a new Account collection. But I don't want to have to define or extend this method in each collection I extend. Something like the following pseudo code:

```
return new instanceof this(this.select(execute));
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure of what you are asking, but I think you want to run a 'where' on an instance of a collection and get back a NEW collection.  Was just playing around in firebug and came up with this:

```
var Chapter  = Backbone.Model;
var chapters = new Backbone.Collection;

chapters.comparator = function(chapter) {
  return chapter.get("page");
};

chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 9, title: "The End"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 5, title: "The Middle"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 1, title: "The Beginning"}));

Backbone.Collection.prototype.where = function(selector) {
 var newCol = new this.__proto__.constructor();
 var itemsToInsert = this.select(selector);
 itemsToInsert.forEach(function(item){ newCol.add(item) });
 return newCol;
};

chapters.where(function(c){ return c.get('page') == 1 });
```

`

This could probably be done better.. but this seems functional.

Comment: Swapping out my code for yours generates errors further down the application, so I am guessing a proper collection is not being returned by this code.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure if the way I'm creating newCol is the right way to do it... what kind of errors?  Might be able to figure it out.. firebug inspect shows that it 'looks' like a backbone collection.

Comment: Yeah, inspecting it looks like a collection but then trying to run collection methods on it throws errors saying they are undefined. For now I'll do it the long way I guess.